# How to create an xml file from a database table using linq?

Tags: xml, linq

I have a sql server 2005 database which contains a user table.. Is it possible to create xml file from the user table? It contains columns like name,age,emailId,mob no etc.. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article may well help you..

http://jacquesbron.com/blog/database/linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-xml-in-action-from-database-to-xml/

I would use Entity Framework or Linq to SQL to get the data out of the database, then use linq to xml to create the desired xml output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can load the data from the DB table, then Linq to XML is exactly what you need.  Check out the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

There are loads of tutorials around, but looking at the MSDN reference for XDocument isn't a bad place to start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

I found this tutorial useful for getting me going when I first needed to do this:

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Answer (score 0):

Just serialize it. `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer` may help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just using an ADO.NET `DataSet`.  It's got built-in XML serialization, and a bunch of other stuff that comes in handy when you're interoperating with a database.